# 'delete' in python removing from every existing list?

Tags: python

Sorry for the titlegore, but I can't think of a better way to describe it.

Just to show what I mean, this:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = a
b.remove(b[0])
print(b)
print(a)
```

outputs this:

```
['2', '3']
['2', '3']
```

when I expected this:

```
['2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
```

Why is this? How would I go about deleting something from the second list while keeping the first the same?

Comment: `a` and `b` are the *same* list.

Comment: use b = a[:] instead of b = a

Comment: With b = a, you don't actually have two lists. The assignment just copies the reference to the list, not the actual list, so both "a" and "b" refer to the same list after the assignment.  Use the syntax as @Reza suggested to get the desired output

Comment: Thank you. I used b = list(a)